# Bash Dialog add buttons and functionality to buttons?

Tags: bash, dialog

I am essentially trying to move from python to bash to reduce overhead but still provide a little GUI functionality.

I have this code and found a way to add a button but I need to add another button and find out how to connect a function to the buttons? one button will call another program to run, the other will stop/kill that other program.

Can somebody show me an example of how to connect a function to a button?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # useradd1.sh - A simple shell script to display the form dialog on screen
    # set field names i.e. shell variables
    call1="w5dmh"
    call2="kd8pgb"
    message="here is a message"

    # open fd
    exec 3>&1

    # Store data to $VALUES variable
    VALUES=$(dialog --extra-button --extra-label "Stop Beacon" --ok-label "Start Beacon" \
      --backtitle "PSKBeacon Setup" \
      --title "PSKBeacon" \
      --form "Create a new beacon" \15 50 0 \
    "From Callsign:" 1 1    "$call2"        1 18 8 0 \
    "To Callsign:"    2 1   "$call1"        2 18 8 0 \
    "Message:"    3 1       "$message"      3 18 25 0 \
     2>&1 1>&3)

            # close fd
            exec 3>&-

    beacon="$call1 $call1 de $call2 $call2 $message"
    [ -e pskbeacon.txt ] && rm pskbeacon.txt
    # display values just entered
    echo $beacon >>pskbeacon.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit status of the `dialog` program tells you what "button" was chosen, and the output of a `dialog` invocation (which you save to the VALUES variable) contains the contents of the form's fields, assuming that one of the "ok" or "extra" choices were made. (You're labeling these "start" and "stop", respectively.)

So, you need to add some code to both check `dialog`'s exit status, and extract values from VALUES. Something like the following, picking up the story after the `dialog` invocation:

```
# Just after the "Store data to $VALUES variable"
# VALUES=$(dialog ... )

ret=$?

# close fd
exec 3>&-

case "$ret" in
  0) choice='START' ;; # the 'ok' button
  1) echo 'Cancel chosen'; exit ;;
  3) choice='STOP' ;; # the 'extra' button
  *) echo 'unexpected (ESC?)'; exit ;;
esac

# No exit, so start or stop chosen, and dialog should have
# emitted values (updated, perhaps), stored in VALUES now

{
  read -r call1
  read -r call2
  read -r message
} <<< "$VALUES"

# setting beacon differently: include choice, and quote form values
beacon="$choice: '$call1' de '$call2' '$message'"

[ -e pskbeacon.txt ] && rm pskbeacon.txt
# display values just entered
echo $beacon >>pskbeacon.txt
```

"Connecting" a function to button, as you say, can be as simple as testing the variable `choice` in my example:

```
if [[ "$choice" = 'START' ]]; then
  echo 'Do something real here for START'
elif [[ "$choice" = 'STOP' ]]; then
  echo 'Do something real here for STOP'
fi
```